# How to play full screen video using fancybox

Tags: video, iframe, fancybox

I am using:

1. fancyBox ----->  to display video in popup window
2. Videojs------->  to play video

The full screen button on video plays it to the size of iframe used in fancybox. I want to play it to actual size of screen... How is that possible...Please help.

Comment: Not sure I understood the question: is the video link inside a regular `<iframe>` tag on your html page? ... so you want to fire fancybox in the parent page, not the "iframed" page?? .... If not, do you mean how to make fancybox as big as your screen?

Comment: Yes the parent page is firing call to fancybox which creates a kind of up window and makes a call to videojs tp play the required video. the videolink is in the html page which calls videojs.

Comment: do you mean that the full screen button (inside fancybox) doesn't toggle to the full size of the window? Could you please some code (js and html) or a link to see the issue? ... it's very hard to help just guessing

Comment: I am having the same issue http://bitstream.ca/beta/

Comment: Check out the following links: http://fancybox.net/ and http://videojs.com/.......The code to integrate the two scripts is: '<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.fancyvideo5").live('click',function(){
        $.fancybox({
        'width'             : '70%',
        'height'            : '50%',
        'autoScale'         : true,
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'type'              : 'iframe',
        'href'              : 'demo.html'
        });
    });
});
 </script>
' Here demo file is in videojs folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use inline HTML instead of iframe - fancybox supports it

```
<a id="inline" href="#data">This shows content of element who has id="data"</a>

<div style="display:none"><div id="data"><video ...>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div></div>
```